# Order of bootstrap and CSS library in header effect h3 Tag

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, browser, bootstrap-4

When I change the order of bootstrap (online) and CSS library(offline-internal) that affect the h3 used in HTML document. let me explain more about the conflict.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://beautifycodes.com/assets/css/main.css" />
```

The sequence of the files and below is the result of the HTML document:
[image]

Now let's change the sequence of the main.css file, h3 tag and logo (have an h1 tag as well) will change its colour, font, size and layout.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://beautifycodes.com/assets/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css"/>
```

now take look at the screenshot below:

[image]

Now my main concern is to just know that where the problem exists in bootstrap.js? bootsrap.css ? or browse have a bug.

Anyone help to understand the reason behind?

Comment: I see same sequence in both code blocks.

Comment: **Sorry for that** code updated...!!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have very little knowledge in how CSS works.
CSS is read by the browser from top to bottom and therefore the order matters. Default bootstrap file already cotains styles for the `H3` tag. You also can define custom styles for `H3` tag inside `main.css`. So if you put bootstrap css file after your main.css file ultimately browser will first apply your main.css style for H3 tag first and within a split second it will again apply the bootstrap css styles. As a result you will finally see the bootstrap styles on the `H3` tag. This can happen vice versa. This is the intended behavior  and how CSS works.

Also browsers don't do mistakes when it comes to css rendering.

Comment: @SpicyBlogging You can vote the answer or mark it as the correct anwser to show your gratitude. 

Answer (score 1):

The order and weight of CSS attributes matter.  When you change the order of your files, it is possible that style that was coming from an earlier file was overwritten once a later file was brought in.

This isn't a bug it's just the nature of CSS.  In addition to order, things like whether you've selected a `Class` or `Id`, the `!important` attribute, and other things will effect the weight of a particular attribute.  If there are competing attributes, the one with the higher weight is applied.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using your custom css (main.css) to style your html page. The order of your CSS files DOES MATTER. When you place your custom css (main.css) file at the end, it will override rest of your css files. And if you place any other CSS file(bootstrap.min.css in this case) after your custom (main.css), it will override your custom CSS file, hence result may vary. Bootstrap.min.css has its own style that is different from your custom css and that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Should be at the top, before all other js.